# Elasticsearch Field Data Cache Distributed?

Tags: java, lucene, nosql, elasticsearch

Since upgrading to Elasticsearch 1.0.1 I've become aware of the field data cache and its circuit breaker.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/index-modules-fielddata.html

I use the facets(and now aggregates) quite heavily and I was just wondering if the field cache is distributed and if so, how it is distributed?

I.e. If I use 2GB of field cache on one node, if I then add 3 more nodes, will the 2GB be distributed over the 4 nodes or will I see a 2GB cache on each node?

Thanks in advance, 
J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of the field data as a data structure that's loaded into memory per shard. You have field data potentially on any data node. It is correct that its memory footprint gets distributed if you scale out by adding more data nodes, although that depends on how many indices/shards you have and which ones you are using for faceting/sorting/scripting.

Comment: Just to clarify then, and lets assume that I've ingested a few million documents using the default 5 shards across 5 physical servers. My understanding from your answer is that if I were to perform say a busy terms facet that used 5GB of field cache, this 5GB would be divided across my 5 shards(assuming they all got hit with the query) meaning 1 GB ish of field cache on each server?

Comment: yep, just remember that if ou have replicas queries go there too. Also, field data is populated by loading all the field values into memory at the first request (or during warmup). That means it just matters if you hit the shards, and which field you facet on, not what type of query you execute against it, since all values for that field will be loaded into memory anyway.